# startinsert mode starts with NSERT -- at top

Tags: original-vim

When I use the command :

```
vim -c "startinsert" sometextfile
```

Vim starts with the characters `NSERT --` at top. The cursor is placed on N and I can write over the whole thing. If I use space, the character remains. If I save and open the file, the characters are gone. If I run vim without my `.vimrc` file, vim starts with `-- INSERT --` at top (because of the line number gone perhaps).

```
---------------------------
  1 NSERT --
~
~
~
~
-------------------
```

OS : macOS High Sierra | version 10.13.3

vim version : version 8.0.642

$TERM = xterm-256color

:echo v:termresponse ( old ) = ^[[>0;95;0c

:echo v:termresponse ( new ) = ^[[>0;95;0c

Comment: Is the `NSERT--` gone when you hit `<Ctrl-L>`? Please expand your question with info about operating system, Vim version and used terminal.

Comment: @Ralf, no the `NSERT --` does not go away upon hitting `<Ctrl-L>`

Comment: @Gautam What if you add  `-u NONE` ?

Comment: @dedowsdi, with `-u NONE`, it does not have the junk characters. But, my line numbers are also gone.

Comment: @Gautam https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file

Comment: @dedowsdi, Thanks, I'll go through the debugging steps and post back.

Comment: Sounds a bit like this bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2008 Can you please update your Vim and see if this still happens? Also please report the terminal you are using and your $TERM variable (and also the output of `:echo v:termresponse`).

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, this issue is resolved upon updating to latest vim. I have updated the question with other details.